# Can Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine be multithreaded

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a number of Visual Studio solutions to build.

Can Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine be used to build multiple solutions at once (i.e. through multithreading)?

I know that it has some STAThread requirement, although I've never quite understood what that means for my programs.

**Edit:** Let me clarify. I know that MSBuild can do multithreaded build of projects in a solution. The question I have is whether [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.aspx) can be used by different threads to build different solutions/projects.

I tried creating separate Engines in different threads, and it didn't work. When I tried using one Engine, in one thread, it worked.

Can the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` .NET libraries build more than one project/solution at a time?

Comment: Are you using TFS? TFS Build can be configured to build multiple builds at a time, on one or more build servers.

Comment: I believe BuildEngine uses MSBuild. But no, I am not using TFS.

Comment: MSBUILD can be called from a TFS2010/2012 build, and the parameters can be passed to make it use multiple threads.

Comment: When it fails to work in multithreaded environment, why not switch to multi-process?

Comment: Unless you are calling COM stuff from the tasks, it should be safe to ignore the STAThread warning (in my experience anyways).

Comment: Paul, did you learn anything around this since you asked the question? I'm about to dig into it as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, I did figure this out. Sadly, I do not work on that project anymore, and I have forgotten what the solution was. (I had forgotten I had asked this question on SO.) I do know that I was able to build projects in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing. Yes you can do multiple parallel project builds (in VS go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run). If you are running MSBuild then you can use the /m[:number] command. As for BuildEngine that has been deprecated in favor of Microsoft.Build.Construction/Microsoft.Build.Evaluation/Microsoft.Build.Execution, which I believe the BuildParameters.MaxNodeCount is what sets the number of threads to use. Although I would personally recommend just running msbuild itself or use the IDE, it's much simpler.

Comment: In .NET 2.0, it is not deprecated, and that is what I am using. I should have mentioned that.
And using an IDE is not easier automated build. And creating a process manually from C# is not quite as elegant as using the libraries made for that purpose.